# How to add number as string to string in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to encrypt the string "aaaabbccdeee" gets converted into "a4bbccde3"

I wasn't able to get it working in one function

Working Solution 1:

```hs
import Data.List (group)
gab0 :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
gab0 = map(\l@(x:xs) -> (x, length l)) . group

gab1 :: (Char, Int) -> String
gab1 (d, 1) = [d]
gab1 (d, 2) = [d] ++ [d]
gab1 (d, x) = [d] ++ show x


gab :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
gab = foldr(\x acc ->  gab1 x ++ acc) [] 

{-
 - gab $ gab0 ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c','c','c','d','e','e']
"a3bc4de2"
-}
```

Solution 2 not working:

```hs
gab2 :: [Char] -> Int -> [Char]
gab2 [x] n 
    | n > 1 = [x] ++ show n
    | otherwise = [x]
gab2 (x:y:xs) n
    | x == y = gab2 (x:xs) (n + 1)
    | otherwise = getnum x :  gab2 (y:xs) 0 
    where getnum a = [a] ++ show n ++ []
```

"aaaabbccdeee" transformed to "a4bbccde3"

Comment: It's completely normal to use helper functions to define something

Comment: You are trying to write too much logic in a single function. It usually is better, software-design-wise to make small reusable components.

Comment: As a note totally unrelated to your question: that fits the modern usage of "encoding" more than "encrypting". Encryption suggests that it's intended to obscure the original. Encoding merely means changing the representation. It also fits with the fact that the process you're implementing usually is called "run-length encoding".

Comment: @Carl This is *almost* RLE, but with an "optimization" that makes it impossible to round-trip if the input string contains any numbers. You really need to convert `"34"` to `"3141"`, rather than `"34"`, if you want to handle all possible inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to compress your first definition into a single function -- i.e. you just need to shuffle some working code around. Haskell is great at this.

I would personally keep `gab1` separate, since it has a couple special cases.  Typically it would be written in curried form

```
gab1 :: Char -> Int -> String
gab1 d 1 = [d]
gab1 d 2 = [d,d]
gad1 d x = [d] ++ show x
```

When `gab0` builds a `(Char,Int)` pair, the only thing it is ever used for is to be passed to `gab1` later.  So we can fuse that layer:

```
gab0 :: String -> [String]
gab0 = map (\l@(x:_) -> gab1 x (length l)) . group
```

Now, since we've moved the application of `gab1` to `gab0` (gosh these need some better names, huh?), `gab` has been reduced to:

```
gab :: [String] -> String
gab = foldr (\x acc -> x ++ acc) [] 
    = foldr (++) []
    = concat
```

(I'm using chained `=` to indicate multiple reductions in a row -- in the real code you need to pick one, but they are all equivalent).

Since `gab` is so simple, why don't we just do it as part of `gab0`?

```
gab0 :: String -> String
gab0 = concat . map (\l@(x:_) -> gab1 x (length l)) . group
```

We can move our `gab1` into a `where` clause since it is only used for a limited scope.  I'm going to rename it to `renderRun`, since it converts a "run" into a string.

```
gab0 :: String -> String
gab0 = concat . map (\l@(x:_) -> renderRun x (length l)) . group
    where
    renderRun d 1 = [d]
    renderRun d 2 = [d,d]
    renderRun d x = [d] ++ show x
```

Is that more to your liking?

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, the solution is fine, sub Tasks / sub Functions are healthy to programmers eyes, so, don't worry, you can create another extra function by compose them:

```
gab2 :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
gab2 = foldr(\x acc ->  gab1 x ++ acc) []

finalGab :: [Char] -> String
finalGab = gab2 . gab0
```